# How Do I Save A Mock API Call To 2 Places Using json-server?

Tags: javascript, json-server

I am using json-server to mock my REST API during testing.

It works fine for POST and GET of the same data. However, I have a requirement to save an audit trail.

This means when I do a POST it needs to save the data to be retrieved by the associated GET but it also needs to be retrieved from the GET in a different API call.

How do I configure json-server to save the POST data in 2 different parts of the db.json?

Comment: Hey, this can be easily achieved by using [@rnmkeshav/mock-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rnmkeshav/mock-api) package as this allows you to write everything(config/routes) in javascript. Give it a try and if you have any issue please raise a ticket on package's github page.

Comment: You should disclose that you are the author of this recommended package.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is how you run it. If you run it with the default method it just saves the POST in the relevant section of the `db.json`.

However, if you can also [run it with express](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#module) to customise it.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js",
  "start-dev": "nodemon index.js",
},
```

This then allows you to write javascript in the `index.js` that gets the contents of the `db.json` and push the data into the audit section as part of the other POST.
e.g.

```
server.post("/data/create", (req, res) => {
  var decodedObj = jwt_decode(req.headers.jwt);
  let db = router.db;

  db.get("audit")
    .push({
      ...req.body,
      status: "New",
      user: decodedObj.name,
    })
    .write();

  const data = db.get("data").value();

  return res.json({
    status: 201,
    data: data[data.length - 1],
  });
});
```